# Can I calculate monochromatic color values with SASS or CSS3?

Tags: css, sass

I would like to be able to specify a base color eg:

```
$basecolor: #ff0000;
```

and calculate other (darker) colors based on that. eg:

```
$backgroundcolor: ($basecolor + rgba(0, 0, 0, .25));
$disabledcolor: ($basecolor + rgba(0, 0, 0, .5));
/* etc */
```

Is this possible?

I'm accomplishing this now by creating an overlay, but that requires me to add extra html, and feels dirty. eg:

```
.overlay25 {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
}
```

Then dropping in:

```
<div class="elementIWantToMakeDarker">
    <div class="overlay25">
        <p>content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: ? http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#darken-instance_method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be to use `darken()` and `lighten()` Sass' native functions:

```
$color:       #123465;
$color_dark:  darken($color, 50%);
$color_light: lighten($color, 50%);
```

You can also use the `mix()` function, which allows you to combine two colors, with a relative weight:

```
$color:       #123465;
$color_dark:  mix($color, black, 50%);
$color_light: mix($color, white, 50%);
```

Comment: sheesh. this is exactly what I needed. Thanks for the speedy response. refactoring now.

Comment: You're welcome. Have a look on [this page](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html), Sass has plenty of native useful functions.